# Prevent sqlalchemy foreign key ID being set to None if the relationship doesn't yet exist

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to import my database from json, and I've hit an issue where attempting to set a foreign key ID before the foreign row is created.

As an example, just say I have a `Parent` and `Child`. This is what is happening:

```
>>> child_data = {'name': 'Ted', dad_id: 2}
>>> c = Child(**child_data)
>>> session.add(c)
>>> session.commit()
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: Child.dad_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO "Child" (name, dad_id) VALUES (?, ?)]
['Ted', None]
```

How can I force it to skip this check, and insert `['Ted', 2]` instead of `['Ted', None]`?

If the child is created first, then the parent, *then* a commit is done, it still fails. I have close to about 30 tables so ordering them will be a pain to figure out.

Comment: This is how SQL works, while this constraint exists you'll not allowed to add Child without a Parent. You can write a script to add whole dads before their child or maybe you can remove this constraint allowing kids without parent before inserts and back the coonstraint after but the second one will cost a lot of time.

Comment: Are you sure about that behaviour? I tried a raw query (`con.execute('SQL: INSERT INTO "Child" (name, dad_id) VALUES (?, ?)', ['Ted', 2])`) and it worked fine. To me it looks more like `sqlalchemy` is the one setting the value to `None`. For the time being I got it working that way, it's just not very pythonic as I have to add in checks to ignore any `column_property` or `polymorphic_identity`.

Comment: Could you add the Child and Parent model declaration?

Answer (score 0):

The message says you are violating `NOT NULL` constraint and not `FOREIGN KEY` one. You have specified key for `dad_id` in `child_data` dictionary as variable and it should be a string. It doesn't crush because you probably specified `dad_id` variable somewhere above. Try this way of defining `child_data`:

```
child_data = {'name': 'Ted', dad_id: 2}
```